# Applying rightsizing recommendations through an API in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I wanted to know if there is a way to apply rightsizing recommendation which is provided for VM using an API call instead of doing it through UI in GCP Compute Engine?

For ex: if there is a VM with config 16vCPUs and 40GB mem, and if the rightsizing recommendation on usage basis is to change the config to 12vCPUs and 20GB, Is there an API available which performs this action?

I know it can be done manually through the interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CLI to change the machine type for a Compute Engine instance.

```
gcloud compute instances set-machine-type INSTANCE --machine-type MACHINE-TYPE
```

Where MACHINE-TYPE can be a predefinded machine type or a custom machine type.

[Predefined Machine Types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#predefined_machine_types)

[Custom Machine Types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type)

The instance must be stopped. Ephemeral external IP addresses might change.

Best practices recommend creating a snapshot of the disks before changing the instance.

[Changing a machine type documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#changing_a_machine_type)

Comment: thanks, its helpful, do you also know a way to get the rightsizing recommendation machine-type value from gcloud command or an api call? I am trying to automate the process, so have to get the value through cmd or call. Thanks again

Comment: No, I do not know of a Google service / API to automate resizing an instance based upon Google recommendations. Also, I would not automate it. Use benchmarks, logging, traffic analysis, etc to correctly size your instances if autoscaling does not provide the granularity that you want.

Comment: Ok Thanks!! @John Hanley