# GCP Using gcloud is it possible to retrieve recommended VM resizes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Can't seem to find any option to retrieve the VM size recommendations that the GCP UI provides in GCE.

Is it possible?

I'm looking to automate the collection of all recommendations so I can automate the process at scale. Iterate through GCP projects - exporting through gcloud the potential savings per project by resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to grab the recommendation message API from GCE in cloud console ? I think they has been receiving these kind of feature requests so you have to ask the support if that it's already implemented.

Comment: thats exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

This post is related with your question [Applying rightsizing recommendations through an API in GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881917/applying-rightsizing-recommendations-through-an-api-in-gcp)

indeed seems like it is not possible to grab these messages out of the console.

Comment: in fact JohnHanley is right from his last comment..I don't know if that should be a good practice but for sure google will enable that request soon. thx for shared it @AlbertoVI that's a nice workaround for now.